# Zabbix send nightly status reports

Tags: reporting, zabbix

Is it possible to define a custom report for Zabbix to email at a specified time each day?

We have people who just want daily summary reports delivered to their inboxes (they do not have access to the Zabbix system, nor the desire to access it) with snapshots of yesterdays SLA's and a few other pieces of information that Zabbix collects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality currently built-in for Zabbix.
There is a community provided patch to send scheduled PDF reports, which might suit your needs : http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18901

Comment: Thanks - from what I've read it looks like what I want, however my Zabbix installations are all the wrong versions to run it.